# how to reset password of root user in MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql

I am accessing MySQL database using workbench 6.3 using root user.but we have forgot password of root user.so how can i reset password of root user

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [MySQL Dev Page - Generic Instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html), (try these in comand line or mysql prompt)

MySQL 5.7.6 and later:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

MySQL 5.7.6 and earlier:

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
```

Kindly refer the [dev page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) for Platform Specific Options.