# MySQL Query Not Executing For Some Reason

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I don't get a single error out of this code, but it is doing absolutely nothing, in regard with the MySQL database, I can't understand why.

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "apm",
  password: "password123"
});

con.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log("[mysql error]",err);
  console.log("Connected!");

  var sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS killEmAll";

  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Database created");
  });

  sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (firstName VARCHAR(255), secondName VARCHAR(255), email VARCHAR(255), username VARCHAR(255), password VARCHAR(255))";

  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Database created");
  });
});
```

The database and the table are not created. The connection is being established, as I get the log "Connected!" (this being the only log).

Comment: All your code is inside the error handler

Comment: Even if my code is inside the error handler, why shouldn't it run?

Comment: If there is an error, therefore have no connection, you are trying to use the connection. If you don't get an error, and have a connection, none of your code gets executed. That is why it doesn't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it this way. This should work:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "apm",
  password: "password123"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected!');
});

var sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS killEmAll";

con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created");
});

con.query('USE killEmAll', function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("killEmAll is using");
})

sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (firstName VARCHAR(255), secondName VARCHAR(255), email VARCHAR(255), username VARCHAR(255), password VARCHAR(255))";

con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created");
});
```

Comment: Connected!
/home/eugen/Documents/nodejs/KillEmAllRealServer/server.js:23
  if (err) throw err;
           ^

Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'apm'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: It seems that problem is in wrong password. Try to reset it. Here is an answer how to do it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46009870/how-to-reset-password-of-root-user-in-mysql-workbench